# How can we get an object reference from a string? What information must such a string contain?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reference, dereference, data-representation

Suppose we have a string, such as `<dict object at 0x0000000000511948>`. How would we then get a reference to the object from that string? If the example given does not contain sufficient information to get a reference to the object, I am willing to change the string.

Basically, we are seeking two functions `obj2str` and `str2obj` such that the following test returns clear:

```
def single_test(obj):
    try:
        assert (str2obj(obj2str(obj)) is obj)
        print('things went well')
        return 0
    except (BaseException, Exception) as exep:
        print('test failed')
        if isinstance(exep, AssertionError) and 'str2obj(obj2str(obj))' in str(exep):
            return 1
        return 999
```

It seems like a good candidate for `obj2str` would be as follows:

```
def obj2str(obj):
    # ignores overridden __repr__ if it is overridden
    return object.__repr__(obj)
```

However, I don't know what we might do for `str2obj`

Comment: Let's just say you can't. Why would you pass around an object's `repr` instead of a reference to the object if you need that object? What are you trying to do here? Also - there'll potentially be some `repr` that return the same string for different objects...and it's only a CPython implementation details that it returns memory addresses - other implementations of Python won't necessary do that...

Comment: There's no guarantee the object even *exists*. It might have been reclaimed long ago.

Comment: @JonClements The reason I was trying to map object references to strings is that I want a container of hashable objects, where each of those hashable objects maps to an object reference. I can create a set from `int`s, because `int`s are hashable, like so: `s = set([1, 2, 3])` However, suppose `lis1` and `list2` are lists. `s = set((lis1, lis2),)` won't work because lists are not hashable. So, I wanted to map the list references to strings (which are hashable), stick the strings into the set, and later map the strings back to the object references.

Comment: Right... If you could explain why you want to do that (what problem you're trying to solve) someone might actually be able to suggest a feasible solution.

Answer (score 0):

In short what you are asking for is impossible.

The string like `<dict object at 0x0000000000511948>` actually tell you the address of the object in the memory. but python is very very high level programming language, so you cannot access the memory (RAM) directly, even if you have the exact address (like in C), all the more you cannot modify the address.

But if you want to use something like this you can simply create a new variable referencing your object instead of the string.

```
your_dict = {'a':5}
new_dict = your_dict
new_dict['a'] = 17
print(your_dict['a'])
$17
```